# Any rule for using nationality as a noun?

Tags: nouns, north-american-english

As you know there are times when using a nationality (without any modification) is a correct way to refer to a person of that nationality and there are times when it is incorrect. For example "He is a German" vs. *"He is a French". 
Are there any rules for deciding if a nationality can be used as a noun?

Comment: Related: [Why isn't USA an attributive adjective, (but US is)?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246012/why-isnt-usa-an-attributive-adjective-but-us-is/246040#246040)

Comment: When there are alternative nouns (Englishman // Frenchman // Scotsman/Scot // Pole ...) the proper-adjective lookalike does not seem available. Essentially, a learner has to check on which usage/s are acceptable.

Comment: When a distinct noun form exists, we use it: Englishman, Dutchman, Italian, Portuguese, .... When not, the adjective may be used as a noun. (Oh! Just read Edwin's comment that seems to say quite the same thing.)

Comment: Please note, however:  it should be *Frenchman,* not *French* in the question, so it's not an example case.

Comment: @Kris "He is a French" is an example of a case where it is incorrect to use nationality as a noun, I know it is wrong that's why I mentioned it in the question to illustrate that point.

Comment: “I'm Spanish” or “I'm a Spanish”? and Why isn't USA an attributive adjective, (but US is)? are obviously not the same question, since they are  specific to those countries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 100% hard-and-fast rule, but in general:

- forms in *-an* (or *-ian*) are used freely as both adjectives and nouns (Germans / German people, Canadians / Canadian people, Africans / African people, etc.).
- forms in *-ese* are used freely as adjectives, and somewhat freely as "substantives" (meaning noun-like adjective uses; e.g. "the Chinese" to refer to Chinese people in general), but not normally as ordinary nouns. (However, some speakers do use phrases like "a Japanese". Also, there exists a noun form "Chinaman", though I wouldn't recommend it nowadays.)
- forms in *-ish*, and *-ch* are like forms in *-ese*, but with the added wrinkle that many of them have corresponding noun forms in *-man*, *-woman*, *-men*, *-women* (a Dutchman, an Irishwoman, two Englishmen, three Frenchwomen). Likewise "Scots" and "Manx". But on the other hand, many form corresponding nouns by *removing* the *-ish* (Swedes, Finns, Poles, Turks, Danes).
- there are various forms that are only or primarily used as nouns. These are frequently colloquial and/or offensive (Jap, Kraut, Yankee, Limey, Russki).
- there are also various other forms, such as "Greek", that are used both as adjectives and as nouns.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Kris: The question was "Are there any rules for deciding if a nationality can be used as a noun?" This answer answers it by . . . well, you can read it for yourself. :-)

Comment: The Q is one thing, this answers quite another. Hope *you* do not need to re-read the two.

Comment: @Kris: I have absolutely no idea what you mean, but whatever. Have a nice day.